# How to update a cell in dataset using C#

Tags: c#

I need to check from a dataset if the value `NOT COMPLETED` exist under the column status then if it does, replace `NOT COMPLETED` with `COMPLETED`. I am using dataset and data adapter in C#. This is what I have done so far. Your help will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
public void check()
{
    DataRow[] cs;

    //search for value of "NOT COMPLETED" in the "case" table in the dataset   
    cs = ds2.Tables["News"].Select("status = 'NOT COMPLETED'");
}
```

Comment: I guess that technically you can't be accused of not having done anything, but this is pretty close to it. Perhaps a little more time Googling might yield some example code you can use.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I dont see a question here, whats the problem?

Comment: how about searching and studying? I see no attempt to do what you want. Please try and show the attempted code before asking.

Comment: thnx for the quick response. i need to edit a update all cell or tuple under status with NOT COMPLETED in the dataset. what i found was passing a new row to the dataset from a form. i added this to it but it only give me error    
                    if (cs.Length > 0)
                    { for (int i =0; i <= cs.Length; i ++)
                    {
                        cs[0] = "N/A".ToString();
                     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all rows, where the status is set to 'NOT COMPLETED' you can take a look at this code:

```
const string news = "news";
const string status = "status";
const string notCompleted = "'NOT COMPLETED'";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(news);
ds.Tables[news].Columns.Add(status);
ds.Tables[news].Rows.Add("test");
ds.Tables[news].Rows.Add(notCompleted);
ds.Tables[news].Rows.Add("dummy");
IEnumerable<DataRow> dataRows = ds.Tables[news].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row[status].ToString() == notCompleted);
```

Comment: How do i use "LIKE" or "CONTAINS" in your example in place of "=="

Comment: Just replace the == to .Contains(notCompleted)

Comment: when i try to output the value of dataRows this is what i get instead of the dataset content. I tried that using a message box. System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Data.DataRow]     how do i get the values from dataRows